# Random Forest for predicting dummie variable

Tags: random-forest, categorical-encoding

I am using a Random Forest model for predicting a target variable wich is basincally 1 and 0 (I have created a dummie variable from a categorical variable). But after running the model I get a predicted variable wich is not only 1 and 0 (as expected) but some values in between (0.something). How can I restrict the predicted value to only 1 and 0? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

- Are you sure that you are not incorrectly using the regression variant of random forest, instead of the classification one?
- It is also possible that your software returns soft classifications, the scores, where you need to [pick a threshold](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Threshold%20classification) to make the hard classifications (zeroes and ones).